# How do I create a generic Firemonkey SOAP client with arbitrary WSDL?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, soap-client, firemonkey

I want to create (for OSX) a simple Firemonkey SOAP client that enables me to specify an endpoint and SOAP method, then pass arbitrary XML inside a SOAP envelope.  It's my job to make sure my XML conforms to the WSDL on the other end; since it's a general-purpose utility there is not one WSDL schema I can wire into the application.

I was able to do this easily in a VCL application on Delphi XE2 using the THTTPReqResp component - works like charm.  But when I try to create a Firemonkey equivalent for this application, it seems like I'm forced to import a specific WSDL and bind to that.  Is there a way to do something more generic?  The various SOAP components seem a lot more complex to work with and I'm not finding either good documentation or demo applications that do what I need to do.

Thanks in advance - E.